# What's the command for making a string into a whole number?

Tags: python

```
print("DOB:")
Year = int(input("Year?"))
Month = int(input("Month?"))
Date = int(input("Date?"))
Birth_Year = 2022 - Year + Month + Date
January = 1
February = 2
March = 3
April = 4
May = 5
June = 6
July = 7
August = 8
September = 9
October = 10
November = 11
December = 12
print("Your DOB is..." + Birth_Year + "!")
```

It should be saying my birth year, but instead it is saying

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\student\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\app.py", line 3, in <module>
    Month = int(input("Month?"))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'December'
```

First of all, yes I am on a student account. Second, I just want the title to be answered.

Comment: You're trying to convert the string "December" into an integer. You are giving the program the name of the month when it asks for the month, but you should be giving it the number of the month. `int("December")` doesn't work, but `int("12")` does.

Comment: Please give specific examples of input and expected output. Also, *int(input())* is rarely a good idea when the input may not be convertible to *int*

Answer (score 2):

If you want to map a string to a related integer, you need a domain-specific function. In the case of months, you should use `datetime.datetime.strptime`

```
m = datetime.datetime.strptime("December", "%B").month
```

`int` *only* turns a string that looks like an integer literal into an integer.

---

You also need to go in the reverse direction, if you want to turn `Birth_Year` into a string.

```
str(Birth_year)
```

But there are numerous ways to avoid the explicit call to `str` (and they are all more efficient than piecing together a single string using `+`):

```
"Your DOB is...%s!" % (Birth_Year,)  # Oldest, least recommended
"Your DOB is...{}!".format(Birth_Year)  # Better, occasionally best
f"Your DOB is...{Birth_Year}!"  # Usually best
```

Comment: Yeah so I tried you suggestion and there is another error message. " Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\student\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\app.py", line 5, in <module>
    Birth_Year = 2022 - float(Year) + float(Month) + float(Date)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'December'

Comment: Why would you try to make any of them `float` values? Even if fractional values made sense, `float` is no more able to turn `'December'` into a floating-point value than `int` can turn it into an integer. `'December'` is not a numeric literal; you can't treat it as such.

Comment: cause a float is a number with a .1, .2 .3 etc..

Answer (score 0):

Here the command you are using to convert a string to a number is correct and you can indeed use `int(string)` assuming the `string` is of a valid number, like say `"3"`. But here as your error message suggests you are trying to pass it an invalid value of `"December"` which cannot be converted to an `int` directly. So perhaps you can use the number of the month instead?

Comment: Yeah but what if I put in November

Comment: @A_Nobody is "`November`" an integer? No. So you can't use `int()` on it.